# Write a query that retrieves suppliers with the characters "wo" and the character "I" or "i" in their name. SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

Write a query that retrieves suppliers with the characters "wo" and the character "I" or "i" in their name.    SQL

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
WHERE SUPPLIER_NAME LIKE '%WO%' 
AND SUPPLIER_NAME LIKE '%L%' OR '%I%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE SUPPLIER_NAME LIKE '%WO%' 
      AND (SUPPLIER_NAME LIKE '%L%' OR SUPPLIER_NAME LIKE '%I%')
```

Comment: If the answer helped you please mark it as correct so the user (who lost their time to help you) has a reputation gain